# WSO2 ESB providing HTTP 202 response on Proxy Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to setup very simple WSO2 ESB Proxy service. While using it, I am getting HTTP 202 response back and WSO2 ESB is not doing anything with the request beside logging it. Here is the background of my setup

My service implementation is using SOAP 1.2 over Http 1.1. When my client opens the connection to the server, it fires first request and asks for keep-alive connection. The ESB passes the request to the actual implementation and sends response back with transfer-encoding as chunked. So far it works as desired.

After the initial request response exchange, my client submits several requests in parallel and I get HTTP 202 responses for all of them. Looking at logs, it seems ESB is not sending the request to the actual implementation ever.

Is there something that I am doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Probably, there is something wrong with the configuration. You can insert some log mediators in the middle and do some debugging. To say what's going wrong, you need to show the ESB configuration (Under source view, in the UI).

Comment: I think I have narrowed down it further. The client application is sending the jsessionid as part of the URL for every request after the first one. As jsessionid is set in URL then it looks like ESB do not recognize the mediation sequence it is supposed to use and hence the HTTP 202 response. How do I make ESB ignore the jsessionid which is part of the URL. Can we use wildcards or some other setting?

Answer (score 1):

What happens in this scenario is that your subsequent requests are hitting the main sequence of the WSO2 ESB. That is why you can only see a log for those requests. As you have already narrowed down this happens due to the jsessionId attached to the URL. To overcome this issue you can create a REST API with URL pattern to match the correct URL path. Please refer the following documentation.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Creating+APIs